# What methods are exposed on the 'User is new' flag in ADB2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure ADB2C in my Xamarin app to provide authentication to my app. One of the 'claims' that ADB2C returns to the app is a 'User is new' bool value which can be used to direct the user journey within the app.

This could be quite useful. However the flag's [true] status persists longer than it is welcome. I would expect that a user 'is new' when they [create an account, login, do some stuff], and after that they are no longer 'new'. The flag seems to change to [false] after an unspecified amount of time.

I cannot find any documentation on how long the 'new' status lasts, or how to push a change.

Answer (score 0):

The user is new flag will be true for first time when authentication happens. If a token is being issued second time, new user flag will be set to false. You can check from network traces, when this value becomes false, was a new token issued?

Comment: No, every time the user authenticates with AcquireTokenSilent it returns "newUser":true